# Is it possible to find the most probable pure state from a mixed state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

Since a mixed state is a normal statistical combination of many pure states, is it possible to find the list of pure state that makes up the mixed state?

I realise there are many different pure states that can combine into the same mixed state, so "disassembling" may produce infinitely many solutions. Is it possible to perhaps find one of the solutions? Or the "most probable" pure state under the classical understanding?

Comment: The title question and the one in the text are different. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I realise there are many different pure states that can combine into the same mixed state, so "disassembling" may produce infinitely many solutions.

This is indeed true. The decomposition of a density matrix into a classical distribution is highly ambiguous (as I explained at depth in [this previous thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/404093/examples-of-density-operators-rho-sum-limits-n-p-n-phi-n-rangle-langle-phi-n)).

However, the loose idea of the "most probable" pure state that helps constitute a given density matrix can indeed be given a unique, rigorous understanding. In essence, a density matrix $\rho$ is a self-adjoint, positive-semidefinite, trace-class operator such that $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho)=1$. The first of those qualifiers is the key, because as a self-adjoint operator you are guaranteed* an eigenvector decomposition of the form
$$ \rho = \sum_n p_n |\phi_n \rangle\langle \phi_n|.$$
There the $|\phi_n\rangle$ are guaranteed to be orthonormal, and they are unique (up to degeneracies). Moreover, the probabilities $p_n$ satisfy $p_n\geq 0$ and $\sum_n p_n =1$.

This structure then lets you take the $|\phi_n\rangle$ with maximal $p_n$ as the "most probable" pure state within the probability distribution.

Moreover, because that maximal $p_n$ coincides with the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) of $\rho$, that "most probable" state can also be defined as the state $|\phi\rangle$ such that
$$
\langle\phi|\rho|\phi\rangle
$$
is maximal over the entire Hilbert space (as can be shown by expanding this $|\phi\rangle$ over the eigenvector basis and then calculating this expectation value).

---

<sup>*modulo mathematical complications in infinite dimensions which require more work, but the assumptions are very strong (the operator is bound, and likely compact) so you get a strong spectral theorem in return.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you take a look at this density matrix? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B5%2F18%2C5%2F18%2C1%2F9%7D%2C%7B5%2F18%2C5%2F18%2C1%2F9%7D%2C%7B1%2F9%2C1%2F9%2C1%2F9%7D%7D

Using wolfram alpha to get the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, it seems the eigenvalues do not add up to 1 as expected. What could be the reason

Comment: @l3utterfly, It's not possible to diagnose the reason why your matrix isn't a density matrix just by looking at its entries (unless it happened to be non-Hermitian, which isn't the case here). Where did that matrix come from?  How did you compute it? The physical details surrounding the matrix are necessary for being able to answer that question. Plus, that's a separate question that likely requires a separate question!  Perhaps in figuring out where the matrix came from, you'll figure out why it's eigenvalues aren't adding to one.

Comment: @l3utterfly The trace of that matrix is 2/3 ;-).

Comment: ... but this is not the place for that kind of question -- take it to [chat].

Comment: My bad. I've got it now.

Answer (score 2):

One possible decomposition is given by the eigenvalue decomposition
$$
\rho = \sum p_k \vert\psi_k\rangle\langle\psi_k\vert\ .
$$
Any other decomposition
$$
\rho = \sum q_\ell \vert\phi_\ell\rangle\langle\phi_\ell\vert$$
is related to this one through
$$
\sqrt{q_\ell}\vert\phi_\ell\rangle = \sum v_{\ell k}\sqrt{p_k}\vert\psi_k\rangle\ ,
$$
where $(v_{\ell k})$ is an isometry, i.e.
$$
\sum_\ell \bar v_{\ell k'}v_{\ell k} = \delta_{k,k'}\ .
$$
(Note that this is an *if and only if*, that is, a full characterization of *all* ensemble decompositions of $\rho$.)