# Showing there are infinitely many decompositions of a non-pure state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states

Consider Problem 2.10 from Ballentine (paraphrased):

> Show (by constructing an example depending on a continuous parameter) that this can be done in infinitely many ways.

I'm not sure how to proceed. I know from a theorem developed in the text that I can write any nonpure state operator $\rho$ as a nontrivial convex combination of other states $\rho^{(i)}$; that is, for valid states $\rho^{(i)}$ I can write
$$\rho = \sum_1^n a_i \rho^{(i)}, a_i \in [0,1]$$

where, importantly, $n \geq 2$, since the theorem's conclusion is that the convex combination must be nontrivial.

I can generate at least one other way of decomposing $\rho$: namely, taking its spectral decomposition, choosing two "pure state" projectors $|\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i|$ and $|\phi_j \rangle \langle \phi_j|$ with eigenvalues $p_i$ and $p_j$, and defining $|\psi_i \rangle = \sqrt{p_i} |\phi_i \rangle + \sqrt{p_j} |\phi_j \rangle$ and $|\psi_j \rangle = \sqrt{p_i} |\phi_i \rangle - \sqrt{p_j} |\phi_j \rangle$. Forming the projectors shows that I can replace the initial two projectors. It's not clear to me how to generalize this example to show that there can indeed be infinitely many such decompositions (in this case I can generate something like ${n \choose 2}$ such decompositions using this strategy).

I am looking for an elementary extension of the example I gave, or at least something closely related (which uses an example depending on a continuous parameter).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142354/discussion-on-question-by-ee18-showing-there-are-infinitely-many-decompositions).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156777/prove-that-the-ensemble-decompositions-of-a-density-operator-rho-are-related, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/404093/examples-of-density-operators-rho-sum-limits-n-p-n-phi-n-rangle-langle-phi-n?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/404241/can-the-same-density-matrix-represent-two-or-more-different-ensembles?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/324296/how-to-decompose-a-density-matrix-of-a-mixed-ensemble-into-a-sum-of-pure-ensembl?noredirect=1&lq=1 (and links therein ;) ).